# I have 2 mailboxes in mail, but only 1 combined inbox

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

I have created two mailboxes in USX mail, but for both of them, I get different sent, spam & trash boxes. But I only have one inbox for both of these mailboxes. Here's a  picture so you really understand what I mean.

[image]

Comment: It´s solved now!

Comment: Welcome to the site. The usual way to indicate a solved question is by accepting the the answer which helped you. You can do this by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: You should accept the answer by @AlistairMcMillan. Also, just a note: *there is no actual question in your question*. In the future, please clearly ask a **question** (followed by a question mark?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the little disclosure triangle beside "Inbox" and Mail will show you the separate Inboxes.

Comment: Ooooh noo. Sorry, i feel like a really rookie now. Well, anyway, thanks for the help!